# Why does Ubuntu One address book not work in Evolution?

Tags: server, ubuntu-one, evolution, contacts

I have troubles getting my Ubuntu One contacts into Evolution. I have set up everything one the u1 dashboard, but when selecting this address book in evolution I get a message telling me that it could not display this address book because of an invalid url or due the inviability of the server. Next to details, it mentions that it has an invalid source. (cannot replicate the original message since it's in dutch...)

When I check the status on u1, it says that there are problems regarding the contacts, but this was on 26/08. So I assume this would be solved by now, or is it?

Could someone tell me how to get things work please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UbuntuOne contacts in evolution use a couchdb file (desktopcouch) which is normally hidden from you. If this file is missing then the url will be invalid.

It could also be a bug since it *should* be clever enough to create an empty couchdb if it's missing. I wonder what would happen if you run the desktop couch stuff from the command line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
How should I run it from the command line? I'm not an expert in this. Could you give me the commands to create an couchdb file please?

Comment: Try `/usr/lib/desktopcouch/desktopcouch-service` it might contain what you need. Unfortunately, I'm not a developer for Canonical on this project so I can't be certain what you need to do.